# Question about wrong type of argument of JavaScript substring method

Tags: javascript

I'm learning basic JavaScript with some simple loop algorithm quizzes.

While making code to print '*'s like a console message below,

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I made the codes like below.

```js
let a = "*****";

for (i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
  console.log(a.substring(a, i));
}
```

I confused role of argument of substring method with replace method's.

I should have to give first argument 0, not a.

But it worked well!

Tried to find a principle at MDN but i couldn't.

Should I understand it as kinda rule when ECMA definiting substring method?

like
'if substring's first argument is string type, it will be regarded as number 0'

What is a principle of this?

Thank you for reading this question written with bad English.

Comment: Automatic type conversion is the keyword. See https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-string.prototype.substring ("_4. Let intStart be ? ToIntegerOrInfinity(start)._").

Comment: If the documentation isn’t detailed enough, go to the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-string.prototype.substring). _“4. Let intStart be ? ToIntegerOrInfinity(start).” → “1. Let number be ? ToNumber(argument). 2. If number is NaN, +0, or -0, return 0.”_.

Comment: Thank you guys for teaching poor fresh newbie so kindly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `substring` method in javascript let you get a selection of string. For example, you want to get the 'test' part in a string of 'testing' you can use `substring` method. The first argument is the string itself and the second argument to this function is a number that will select a number of characters from the string.
In your program, you select a number of `*` based on the value of `i` in the loop.
Here is a simple example of `substring` method.

```js
const test = "testing";
console.log(test.substring(test,2)) // output 'te'
console.log(test.substring(test,4)) // output 'test'
```

Comment: Thank you guys for teaching poor fresh newbie so kindly :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe its duo to "type coercion" in JavaScript, which means **the automatic or implicit conversion of values from one data type to another**

In your example, JavaScript needs a first argument of type Number, as you provide a string, it first looks if the string can be converted to number, like `"3"` is a string but can be converted. since your first argument is a string that isn't meaningful as a number, it is converted to 0.

Comment: Thank you guys for teaching poor fresh newbie so kindly :)